# How to fix 'configure: incompatible neon library version 0.29.3: wanted 0.25 26 27 28'

Tags: linux, autotools, webdav

I am trying to configure webdav. When I run `./configure` it ends with:

```
checking for neon-config... /usr/bin/neon-config
checking linking against neon... yes
configure: incompatible neon library version 0.29.3: wanted 0.25 26 27 28
configure: error: could not find neon
```

I could not find the 0.25/0.26/0.27/0.28 versions of neon-devel.

Where or how can I install the compatible version of neon-devel?

---

Output:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking for neon-config... /usr/bin/neon-config
checking linking against neon... yes
configure: incompatible neon library version 0.29.3: wanted 0.25 26 27 28
configure: error: could not find neon
```

Comment: `0.29.3` seems greater/higher than `0.25`,  `0.26`, etc. You may need to fix `configure.ac`. It could be 0.29 is too high, but my experience is `configure.ac` needs updating.

Comment: webdav is a protocol, not a specific project, so it's unclear what it is that you're actually trying to build.  In any event, you should consider looking for a more recent version of that package, or an alternative package, as neon 0.29 is some 10 years old now.

Comment: But Fedora Koji does have [neon-0.28](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=127836), and even version 0.25, in SRPM form.  Even if you're not on an RPM-using distribution, the SRPM contains a source distribution of the software, which you should be able to extract and build.

Answer (score 0):

As jww pointed out, a solution is to edit configure.ac. And if it works to submit this change upstream.

But you can probably get away with just editing the configure script. Look for the string 26 27 28 and add 29 at the end.

Since the author of the software you are trying to compile didn't test this combination, there is of course the chance that there were incompatible changes in neon and it doesn't work.